# Weird event handling bug when CSS adjusts to URL in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, event-handling

EDIT: this issue is due to my custom CSS adjustment running twice. Solution imminent.

I'm trying to create a component-level event handler in a React website (arrow navigation in an image gallery / slider).

The following is my implementation wrapped inside a useEffect hook. I'm new to React. To be honest, I'm just beginning to understand hooks.

I have another function that reads out the URL to get the last number, for example /0 or /5, to automatically adjust the container's left CSS value, so it focuses on the correct image (the one corresponding to the number inside the URL string). This is working. React's useParams did not.

The weird part is that my arrow navigation ONLY works flawlessly when the URL ends on /0 (adjusting image wrappers so that the first one has left:0%).

When I load the page with say "http://....images/1", the left arrow has to be pressed two or three times, and the right arrow makes things slide by 2 images. Additionally, the conditional fails so that in this case, also all other keys produce a right-arrow-left-slide.

This is one of the many crazy bugs I encounter with React. Things that sometimes work and sometimes fail are just no way to be productive.

```
React.useEffect(function setupListener() {
        function handleKeyPress(evt) {

            const wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('bilderwrapper')
            if(document.querySelector('.bilderwrapper') !== null) {
                //evt = evt || window.event
                //alert(evt.keyCode)

                if (evt.keyCode === 37) {

                    if (wrappers[0].style.left !== '0%') slide('left')
                }
                else if (evt.keyCode === 39) {

                    if (wrappers[wrappers.length-1].style.left !== '0%') slide('right')
                }
                // re-focus on now centered art
                currentArt()
                // check buttons
                checkForUnnecessaryArrows()
            }
    
        }
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)

        return function cleanupListener() {
          window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
        }
    })
```

This is the code bit that moves stuff:

```
const getCSSLeftAsBareNumber = (obj) => {
        // get css value str:
        const origLeft = obj.style.left
        // cut off '%':
        const bareNum = origLeft.substring(0,origLeft.length-1) 
        return(parseInt(bareNum))
        // return bareNum
    }

    const slide = dir => {
        const wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('bilderwrapper')
        if (dir === "left") {
            wrappers.forEach((wrap) => {
                const number = getCSSLeftAsBareNumber(wrap)
                console.log(number)
                wrap.style.left = (number+100)+'%'
            })
        }
        else if (dir === "right"){
            wrappers.forEach((wrap) => {
                const number = getCSSLeftAsBareNumber(wrap)
                console.log(number)
                wrap.style.left = (number-100)+'%'
            })
        }
    }
```

I've wrapped the whole URL-ending-CSS-adjust function inside a useEffect(), and there was one minor improvement: now the left arrow slide begins with a slight jerk in the slide direction. And the left arrow now has to be pressed 2 times, never 3. Only when I previously pressed the left arrow, the right arrow responds to only 1 press.

I'm unable to create a reproducible minimal example. The whole project is at https://github.com/NeilSentence/galerie-sens

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect() hook that contains the URL-based layout adjustment ran twice. It took CSS values, recomputed them, and updated the starting values. Because it did that twice, the error was greater, the higher the slug number was.

For Ex. "/images/1" created a left-shift by 2, "images/3" by 6. The crazy part that I don't fully understand is why the arrow navigation logic got messed up by this to the point that even the alt key started behaving like a right arrow.

The solution was to force the useEffect() hook to run only once by

````
const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(false)

React.useEffect(() => {

    if (!firstRender) {
        //all code here
        setFirstRender(true)
    }

```
````